# Display only True values in a dictionary

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to display the permissions of a member from a dict as in

```
permdict = {
                    'Administrator': f'{member.guild_permissions.administrator}',
                    'Ban Members': f'{member.guild_permissions.ban_members}',
                    'Kick members': f'{member.guild_permissions.kick_members}'}
```

at this moment this will return something like :

```
{'Administrator': 'True', 'Ban Members': 'True', 'Kick members': 'True'}
```

or false if the user doesn't have these permissions, my goal is to be able to filter the keys which have True values, so if the user have just x/3 permissions (the dictionary will be bigger, but i don't want to proceed further unless i am able to solve my problem), to show just the Key with True value and if the user has none of the permissions in the dictionary it will return nothing or a string ex `You have no moderation roles to dispaly` and if some of the perms are present to display them just by key `Administrator, Kick members` etc. . . I didn't  worked too much with bools inside dictionaries so i hoped i can find a solution here.

i also tried to combine it with `.join`:

```
 permdict = {'Administrator': f'{member.guild_permissions.administrator}',
                    'Ban Members': f'{member.guild_permissions.ban_members}',
                    'Kick members': f'{member.guild_permissions.kick_members}'}

 permf = ", ".join(permdict) ​
```

And the result was what i desired

```
Administrator, Ban Members, Kick members ​
```

but the problem was that even if the user didn't had these perms they will still be displayed. I feel like i'm quite close to find a solution but i can't figure it out

Comment: Why are you storing the values as strings rather than booleans?

Comment: @Barmar how else i could do it then? i mean, naturally you would do Key: True/False .   But without ``guild_permissions`` method i can't check whether the member has those permissions or not, i did this because it looks "more beautiful" because i don't want to be returned a whole list of perms

Comment: Don't use the f-string, just `'Administrator': member.guild_permissions.administrator`

Comment: It's not even clear why you need your own dictionary. `member.guild_permissions` is already a dictionary with all the permissions. The only difference is capitalization.

Comment: i want my own dict because i want to list the moderation permissions someone have(if they have ofc), ``member.guild_permissions`` returns a dictionary  of all permissions, default ones included, and i end up with over 20-30 perms which i don't need, and as i said above, looks more beautiful and clean, because they're listed with underscore like ``ban_members`` and imo looks cleaner ``Ban Members``

Comment: also, i removed the f-strings and i changed ``if value == "True"`` to ``if value is True`` and it works like before,  but i feel like it's a bit slower or maybe it's just me

Comment: Just use `if value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a generator with a condition:

```
permf = ", ".join(key for key, value in permdict.items() if value == "True")
```

You can simplify things a bit if you change `permdict` to contain booleans instead of strings.

```
permdict = {
    'Administrator': {member.guild_permissions.administrator,
    'Ban Members': member.guild_permissions.ban_members,
    'Kick members': member.guild_permissions.kick_members
}
permf = ", ".join(key for key, value in permdict.items() if value)
```

Comment: Even better: don't stringify the booleans in the dictionary, and the condition can just be `if value`

Comment: I know. See the comment I posted a few minutes ago.

Comment: `value == "True"` won't work since `"True"` is a str(ing) and `value` is a bool(ean). You need to do it without the quotes and `if value` is even better. Also you should use `is` instead of `==`

Comment: @WasiMaster `value` is a string because he created it with an f-string.

Comment: @Barmar Oh wait I didn't notice that lol, ignore my comment I guess